# perform a segue from a addressbook modal

Tags: ios, mobile, swift, xcode5

i'm with a problem to show a new viewController from a modal contacts what is load from  **ABPeoplePickerNavigationController**!

The problem is, when i show all contacts i want to open a new view when i click on it. but i'm having a  error.

in the main controller i have the method that show the contact list (with is a button action):

```
@IBAction func showContacts(sender : AnyObject) {
   self.addressBookController.peoplePickerDelegate = self
   self.presentViewController(addressBookController, animated: true, completion: nil)          
}
```

This open the list of contacts. But when i click on some of then i receive the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

(lldb)

i've created a new viewcontroller and a link between the atual viewcontroller and the new view and labeled the segue as 'teste'.

than i have the methods:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "teste"{
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as SelecionaNumeroViewController

    }
}
```

and the perform segue:

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController( peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {

    self.addressBookController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.navigationController.performSegueWithIdentifier("teste", sender: self)

}
```

I think this is a newbie problem, but I can't find the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the solution.

i forgot to put the new viewcontroller into the navigation controller:

i did:

> Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller

and it's work!